Flutter and MariaDB - Socket Exception
I am writing an app in Flutter. I am trying to connect to MariaDB which is running on my local desktop.
The app was running fine till last night but this morning, I could not start MariaDB. In the end, I installed XAMPP afresh and copied ibdata1 file. Now, MariaDB is running but I am unable to connect to MariaDB from Flutter.
I am getting this error on the screen - Error:SocketException:Socket has been closed.
First, I was running the app from my Android Phone but as I was getting the error, I tried switching to emulator. But the same error is occurring.
My Flutter Code:
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static final _dbHost = '192.168.0.137';
  static final _dbPort = 3306;
  static final _dbName = 'seasonpass';
  static final _dbUser = 'root';
  static final _dbPassword = ''; // Your password here

  static Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    final settings = ConnectionSettings(
      host: _dbHost,
      port: _dbPort,
      db: _dbName,
      user: _dbUser,
      password: _dbPassword,
    );

    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}

Sample snapshot of netstat is produced below (not sure if this is helpful):
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51569  TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51574  TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51587  TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:49262  ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:49366  ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51382  ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51423  ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51555  TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51556  TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:51560  TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.0.137:64800    227:https              ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.137:64943    227:https              ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.137:65441    192.168.0.172:8009     ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.0.137:65445    192.168.0.172:8009     ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:57607            DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:57620  ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:57611            DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:57630  ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:57620            DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:57607  ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:57630            DESKTOP-I1P4IJE:57611  ESTABLISHED

Below is the output of Shell command from XAMPP:
Anirban@DESKTOP-I1P4IJE c:\xampp
# mysql -h localhost -u root -p --protocol=TCP
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 57
Server version: 10.4.32-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> select Host, User from mysql.user;
+-----------+------+
| Host      | User |
+-----------+------+
| %         | root |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |
| ::1       | root |
| localhost | pma  |
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> mysql -u root -p \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.32-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491

Connection id:          57
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.4.32-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 34 min 43 sec

Threads: 6  Questions: 1750  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 39  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 32  Queries per second
[
Copy of Log file with error:
2024-04-21 18:40:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=2] log sequence number 6341971 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 47151.
2024-04-21 18:40:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=3, page number=2] log sequence number 132028 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114478.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=3, page number=3] log sequence number 128100 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114478.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=3, page number=4] log sequence number 129368 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114478.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=3, page number=5] log sequence number 130664 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114478.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=3, page number=6] log sequence number 132028 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114478.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=4, page number=0] log sequence number 136697 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114478.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2024-04-21 19:00:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=4, page number=1] log sequence number 132636

After noticing the error in the log file, I deleted the contents of data folder, copied the content of backup folder into the data folder and imported the databases earlier kept as backup (mydash.sql and seasonpass.sql).
Below is the current log file excerpt:
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 36804
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=8849071
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 8849080; transaction id 1418
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240423  8:48:27
2024-04-23  8:48:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

I am still getting the socket error.

"installed XAMPP afresh copied ibdata1" - what official document describes this a process that would work? Do you have a backup copy of your entire datadir (keep it safe, you will need it)? Edit your question to include the MariaDB logs from around the time of failure?
